# SQL Get Parent when child is column is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have two tables below.

```
CREATE TABLE Name
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(256)
)

CREATE TABLE BranchAddress
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId INT NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT NOT NULL,
    IsNetwork BIT,
    Address VARCHAR(256)
)
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Name ( Name )
VALUES ('George'), ('Greg')

INSERT INTO BranchAddress (UserId, ParentId, IsNetwork, Address)
VALUES (1, 0, 1, 'Kings Street'), (1, 1, 0, 'GS Road'),
       (1, 0, 0, 'Nariman Point'), (1, 1, 1, 'St. College Street'),
       (1, 2, 1, 'PG National Road'), (1, 1, 0, 'LOS India')
```

Using joins I have got the information from both the tables which have needed, but in a new case I need to extract the `Address` like if the `IsNetwork = 0` then Address should of it's the **parent**.

Following is the query of join

```
SELECT 
    t.Id, t.Name, t2.ParentId, t2.IsNetwork, t2.Address 
FROM 
    dbo.Name t 
INNER JOIN 
    BranchAddress t2 ON t.Id = t2.UserId
```

This is the output of that query:

```
Id          Name    ParentId IsNetwork    Address
----------- ------- ----------- --------- -------------------------
1           George  0           1         Kings Street
1           George  1           0         GS Road
1           George  0           0         Nariman Point
1           George  1           1         St.College Street
1           George  2           1         PG National Road
1           George  1           0         LOS India
```

I want the output as below.

```
Id          Name    ParentId IsNetwork    Address
----------- ------- ----------- --------- -------------------------
1           George  0           1         Kings Street
1           George  1           0         Kings Street
1           George  0           0         Kings Street
1           George  1           1         St.College Street
1           George  2           1         PG National Road
1           George  1           0         Kings Street
```

Comment: Is there any column for sorting the rows? otherwise it's difficult.

Comment: In your expected output, for Nariman Point address also, you wanted Kings street even though its parent is 0. Is that a typo?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` to `BranchAddress` a second time to get the `Address` of the parent, then select which address to return based on the `IsNetwork` value of the original row:

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Name, b1.ParentId, b1.IsNetwork, 
       CASE WHEN b1.IsNetwork = 0 THEN b2.Address
            ELSE b1.Address
       END AS Address
FROM Name n
INNER JOIN BranchAddress b1 ON n.Id = b1.UserId
LEFT JOIN BranchAddress b2 ON b2.ID = b1.ParentId
```

Output

```
Id  Name    ParentId    IsNetwork   Address
1   George  0           true        Kings Street
1   George  1           false       Kings Street
1   George  1           false       Kings Street
1   George  1           true        St. College Street
1   George  2           true        PG National Road
1   George  1           false       Kings Street
```

Note that the entry for `Nariman Point` had an invalid `ParentId` (`0`) and I've changed that to `1` (to be consistent with the expected results) for the demo.

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cb10d/1)

Answer (score 1):

In your expected output, for Nariman Point address also, you wanted Kings street even though its parent is 0. Is that a typo?.

```
SELECT t.Id,t.Name,t2.ParentId,t2.IsNetwork,
     case when t2.isNetWork = 0 and t2.ParentId > 0  then t3.Address else t2.Address end as Address
     FROM [dbo].[Name] t 
     INNER JOIN dbo.BranchAddress t2 ON t.Id = t2.UserId
     left JOIN dbo.BranchAddress t3 on t3.id = t2.ParentId
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra left join to parent zero that's a network.
But only for the non-network addresses.

```
SELECT 
usr.Id, 
usr.Name,
addr1.ParentId, 
addr1.IsNetwork,
COALESCE(addr2.Address, addr1.Address) as Address2
FROM dbo.Name usr
INNER JOIN BranchAddress addr1
  ON addr1.UserId = usr.Id
LEFT JOIN BranchAddress addr2
  ON addr2.UserId = usr.Id
 AND addr2.ParentId = 0
 AND addr2.IsNetwork = 1
 AND addr1.IsNetwork = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `SELECT * FROM [Name]` FIRST

```
SELECT t.Id,t.Name,t2.ParentId,t2.IsNetwork,t2.Address 
FROM [Name] t LEFT OUTER JOIN BranchAddress t2 ON t.Id = t2.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

**you Can try this to pick Parent

```
Select t.Id,t.Name,t2.ParentId,t2.IsNetwork,case when IsNetwork = 0 then (select Address from BranchAddress where Id in (select min(Id) from BranchAddress)) else t2.Address end 'Address' 
FROM dbo.Name t 
INNER JOIN BranchAddress t2 
ON t.Id = t2.UserId
```